# Nested divs are overlapping when divs are smaller than others

Tags: html, css

I am working on a page with a Wrapper div which is the container.

I have 1 div in on right which is using float to stay there. When the main container which is to the left is smaller than the right container, the right container seems to over lap the wrapper.

**HTML**

```
    <body>
    <div id="Wrapper">
        <div id="Title">Title</div>
        <div id="SubTitle">SubtTitle</div>
        <br />
        <div id="Menu">Home | Our Story | Share A Memory | Information | About Us</div>
        <br />
        <div id="CountDown">
            <div id="CountDownTitle">Title</div>
            <hr />
            Some<br />
Random<br />
stuff<br />
        </div>
        <div id="Info">
            This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. This is a test. This is only a test. 
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background-image: url('../PNGs/Background.png');
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
    font-size: 14px;
}
#CountDown {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px black solid;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0px, 0px, #000000;
    width: 20%;
}
#CountDownTitle {
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Pristina;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    src: url('../Elements/PRISTINA.ttf');
    text-align: center;
}
#Info {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px black solid;
    font-family: "Palatino Linotype";
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 0.6;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-shadow: 0px, 0px, #000000;
    width: 70%;
}
#Menu {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px black solid;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    width: 100%;
}
#SubTitle {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Pristina;
    font-size: 18px;
    src: url('../Elements/PRISTINA.ttf');
    text-align: center;
}
#Title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Pristina;
    font-size: 48px;
    src: url('../Elements/PRISTINA.ttf');
    text-align: center;
}
#Wrapper {
    border: 1px black solid;
    clear: both;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 75px;
    width: 800px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you want. If I understand when #info content is poor #wrapper border overlaps #CountDown content. Is it your issue ? __ like we see at http://jsfiddle.net/nmHFt/2/ __

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden;` to your Wrapper div

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BNDKL/)**

With little content: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BNDKL/1/)**

The reason this works is because when overflow isn't set to visible (the default) this creates a new block formatting context.

When a div creates a new block formatting context it stretches in height to contain its floating elements (assuming the div itself does not have a specified height.)